# Getting different results when using the sparklyr and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

Just now i start learning the sparklyr package using the reference [sparklyr](http://spark.rstudio.com/)
 i did what was  written in the document. 
when using the following code

```
delay <- flights_tbl %>% 
  group_by(tailnum) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), dist = mean(distance), delay = mean(arr_delay)) %>%
  filter(count > 20, dist < 2000, !is.na(delay)) %>%
  collect

Warning messages:
1: Missing values are always removed in SQL.
Use `AVG(x, na.rm = TRUE)` to silence this warning 
2: Missing values are always removed in SQL.
Use `AVG(x, na.rm = TRUE)` to silence this warning 

> delay
# A tibble: 2,961 x 4
   tailnum count  dist  delay
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 N14228  111    1547  3.71 
 2 N24211  130    1330  7.70 
 3 N668DN   49.0  1028  2.62 
 4 N39463  107    1588  2.16 
 5 N516JB  288    1249 12.0  
 6 N829AS  230     228 17.2  
 7 N3ALAA   63.0  1078  3.59 
 8 N793JB  283    1529  4.72 
 9 N657JB  285    1286  5.03 
10 N53441  102    1661  0.941
# ... with 2,951 more rows
```

In the similar way i want apply the same operations on  `nycflights13::flights` dataset using `dplyr` package

```
nycflights13::flights %>% 
    group_by(tailnum) %>%
    summarise(count = n(), dist = mean(distance), delay = mean(arr_delay)) %>%
     filter(count > 20, dist < 2000, !is.na(delay)) 

# A tibble: 1,319 x 4
   tailnum count  dist   delay
   <chr>   <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 N102UW     48   536   2.94 
 2 N103US     46   535 - 6.93 
 3 N105UW     45   525 - 0.267
 4 N107US     41   529 - 5.73 
 5 N108UW     60   534 - 1.25 
 6 N109UW     48   536 - 2.52 
 7 N110UW     40   535   2.80 
 8 N111US     30   536 - 0.467
 9 N11206    111  1414  12.7  
10 N112US     38   535 - 0.947
# ... with 1,309 more rows
```

My problem is why i am getting the different results ?

As mention in the documentation  `dplyr` is the complete backend operations 
for `sparklyr`.

```
 > sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2   dplyr_0.7.4    sparklyr_0.7.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] DBI_0.7            readr_1.1.1        withr_2.1.1       
 [4] nycflights13_0.2.2 rprojroot_1.3-2    lattice_0.20-35   
 [7] foreign_0.8-69     pkgconfig_2.0.1    config_0.2        
[10] utf8_1.1.3         compiler_3.4.0     stringr_1.3.0     
[13] parallel_3.4.0     xtable_1.8-2       Rcpp_0.12.15      
[16] cli_1.0.0          shiny_1.0.5        plyr_1.8.4        
[19] httr_1.3.1         tools_3.4.0        openssl_1.0       
[22] nlme_3.1-131.1     broom_0.4.3        R6_2.2.2          
[25] dbplyr_1.2.1       bindr_0.1          purrr_0.2.4       
[28] assertthat_0.2.0   curl_3.1           digest_0.6.15     
[31] mime_0.5           stringi_1.1.6      rstudioapi_0.7    
[34] reshape2_1.4.3     hms_0.4.1          backports_1.1.2   
[37] htmltools_0.3.6    grid_3.4.0         glue_1.2.0        
[40] httpuv_1.3.5       rlang_0.2.0        psych_1.7.8       
[43] magrittr_1.5       rappdirs_0.3.1     lazyeval_0.2.1    
[46] yaml_2.1.16        crayon_1.3.4       tidyr_0.8.0       
[49] pillar_1.1.0       base64enc_0.1-3    mnormt_1.5-5      
[52] jsonlite_1.5       tibble_1.4.2       Lahman_6.0-0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key difference is that in the non-sparklyr, we are not using `na.rm = TRUE` in `mean`, therefore, those elements having `NA` in 'distance' or 'arr_delay' will become NA when we take the `mean` but in `sparklyr` the NA values are already removed so the argument is not needed

We can check the `NA` elements in 'distance' and 'arr_delay'

```
nycflights13::flights %>% 
       summarise_at(vars(distance, arr_delay), funs(sum(is.na(.))))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  distance arr_delay
#     <int>     <int>
#1        0      9430  #### number of NAs
```

So, if we correct for that, then the output will be the same

```
res <- nycflights13::flights %>% 
    group_by(tailnum) %>%
    summarise(count = n(),
              dist = mean(distance, na.rm = TRUE),
              delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
     filter(count > 20, dist < 2000, !is.na(delay))  %>%
     arrange(tailnum)
res
# A tibble: 2,961 x 4
#   tailnum count  dist   delay
#   <chr>   <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 N0EGMQ    371   676   9.98 
# 2 N10156    153   758  12.7  
# 3 N102UW     48   536   2.94 
# 4 N103US     46   535 - 6.93 
# 5 N104UW     47   535   1.80 
# 6 N10575    289   520  20.7  
# 7 N105UW     45   525 - 0.267
# 8 N107US     41   529 - 5.73 
# 9 N108UW     60   534 - 1.25 
#10 N109UW     48   536 - 2.52 
# ... with 2,951 more rows
```

Using `sparklyr`

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")


flights_tbl <- copy_to(sc, nycflights13::flights, "flights")

delay <- flights_tbl %>% 
  group_by(tailnum) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), dist = mean(distance), delay = mean(arr_delay)) %>%
  filter(count > 20, dist < 2000, !is.na(delay)) %>% 
  arrange(tailnum) %>%
  collect
delay
# A tibble: 2,961 x 4
#   tailnum count  dist   delay
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 N0EGMQ  371     676   9.98 
# 2 N10156  153     758  12.7  
# 3 N102UW   48.0   536   2.94 
# 4 N103US   46.0   535 - 6.93 
# 5 N104UW   47.0   535   1.80 
# 6 N10575  289     520  20.7  
# 7 N105UW   45.0   525 - 0.267
# 8 N107US   41.0   529 - 5.73 
# 9 N108UW   60.0   534 - 1.25 
#10 N109UW   48.0   536 - 2.52 
# ... with 2,951 more rows
```

Comment: @ Thankyou akrun i should read more about both dplyr and sparklyr.